# spell correction for ASR model python

Tags: python, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, bert-language-model

I have `ASR` model trained for `persian-language` but my model have some typo and I want to fix that on `NLP` layer, I want to know what option I have, but I can't find the good code to that, So I have `30K-clean-sentences` and `audio` for **train** `ASR-model` then I use the sentences as **correct** sentence and I use my model to find the `typo or misspelling`, now I have 3**0k clean and correct** sentences and almost **15k misspelling sentences**, how can I create model to fix this?